# Upload file attached to a DropDownList value?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I currently have a form in which i have a DropDownList, a FileUpload object and a Button to submit the FileUpload.
The DropDownList is connected to a SqlDataSource which queries for last names from a table in my database, so the DropDownList displays said last names. I was just wondering is it possible to upload a file attached to the value in the DropDownList? So that it could later be used if someone wants to download a file uploaded by a specific person. I have been searching for quite a while now and haven't found any information on this so any help would be appreciated.
Here is my form code:

```
<p>
    Choose student:</p>
<p>
    <asp:DropDownList ID="DropDownList1" runat="server" 
        DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" DataTextField="stulastname" 
        DataValueField="stulastname">
    </asp:DropDownList>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [stulastname] FROM [application]"></asp:SqlDataSource>
</p>
<p>
    Leave comments:</p>
<p>
    <asp:TextBox ID="TextBox1" runat="server" Height="159px" Width="482px"></asp:TextBox>
</p>
<p>
    <asp:Button ID="Button2" runat="server" onclick="Button2_Click" 
        Text="Insert Comments" />
</p>
<p>
    Upload comments:</p>
<p>
    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
    <asp:RegularExpressionValidator id="FileUpLoadValidator" runat="server" ErrorMessage="Upload text documents only" ValidationExpression="^(([a-zA-Z]:)|(\\{2}\w+)\$?)(\\(\w[\w].*))(.txt|.doc)$" ControlToValidate="FileUpload1"></asp:RegularExpressionValidator>
</p>
<p>
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" onclick="Button1_Click" 
        Text="Upload File" />
</p>
```

Here is my current code behind code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.Sql;
using System.Data;
using System.IO;

public partial class PS_comments : System.Web.UI.Page
{
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
    {
        string FileName = FileUpload1.FileName;

        SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\\Assignment\\App_Data\\MyDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
        SqlCommand cmd;
        con.Open();
        con.Close();
        cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE application SET filename= '" + FileName + "' WHERE stulastname = '" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "' ");
        cmd.Connection = con;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/userfiles");
        bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(path);
        if (!isExists)
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
        var file = Path.Combine(path, FileUpload1.FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(file);
    }
}
protected void Button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\\Assignment\\App_Data\\MyDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
    SqlCommand cmd;
    con.Open();
    cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE application SET comments = '" + TextBox1.Text + "' WHERE stulastname = '" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "' ");
    cmd.Connection = con;
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
}
```

Comment: why are you not using value of DropDownList1 value where you are checking FileUpload1.HasFile

Comment: @ParvSharma sorry, i don't understand what you're trying to explain?

Answer (score 0):

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            string FileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;

            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(
                "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;
                 AttachDbFilename=E:\\Assignment\\App_Data\\MyDatabase.mdf;
                 Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
            SqlCommand cmd;
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE application 
                                  SET filename= '" + FileName + "' 
                                  WHERE stulastname = '" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "' ");
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/userfiles");
            bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(path);
            if (!isExists)
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            var file = Path.Combine(path, FileUpload1.FileName);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(file);
        }
    }
```

Comment: i am getting the error "'string' does not contain a definition for 'Combine' and no extension method 'Combine' accepting a first argument of type 'string' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)"

Comment: is there a specific using directive that i need to be able to use this method?

Comment: i have added the current using directives to my original post

Comment: wait sorry, that error as gone but now in the line of "var file = Path.Combine(path, FileUpload1.FileName);" i am getting an error which is "The name "Path" does not exist in the current context"

Comment: You need `System.IO` to use `Path`.

Comment: Thank you, the function now works and inputs the filename into the database attached to the user but it doesn't upload the file. i tried changing the path to a folder i have already created but it still doesn't upload, any thoughts?

Comment: Did u check in the correct project path  urproejectName\App_Data\userfiles.It should be there

Comment: @Nadee ah sorry it did upload the file into that directory but now when i test it, it doesn't work at all. It doesnt upload the file or enter the filename into the database. I have edited my initial post to show exactly what i have in my code behind file so you can check if i made a mistake

Comment: Just now i check ur code.  pls change string FileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;

Comment: Then it should work .I have tested it locally now.Still its not working try to execute the update sql statement in sql query edtior

Comment: Like this --  UPDATE application 
SET filename= 'abc.docx' 
WHERE stulastname ='john'

Comment: I used "UPDATE application SET filename = 'abc.doc' WHERE stulastname = 'smith' " but it didnt update the database field

Comment: check is there a record in the table where stulastname = 'smith' , select * from application where stulastname = 'smith'.If no record found then that is the reason to not to update

Comment: there is an entry with the last name "smith". here is a screenshot i took of the test query from my dropdownlist http://tinypic.com/r/14b7vgo/5

Comment: Im wondering why its not working.because i have tested ur code from my side.send me the whole code

Comment: i am confused myself, here is a download link to the whole project http://www.sendspace.com/file/bd9us8

Comment: send me ur application table create script

Comment: really? its not working on my computer though :L, what is my application table create script? i just created the tables in the server explorer

Comment: No  bigsenator. the table u have insert records stulastname, comments, files etc. The name of that table is application right? Just send me the create table script of that table

Comment: oh okay, how do i find the create table script for 'application'?

Comment: go to Server Explorer. seletc the table 'application' from data connections. right click on 'application' , select properties. or select showtable data.
then send me a screenshot of it

Comment: ohh that's what you meant haha, can't you just view it in the file i sent you? I sent you the whole project

Comment: cant. i don't have ur database connection. that can only view by ur self :(

Comment: ohh right, here is a screenshot of the application table data, it was too long to fit into a single screenshot so i just put the last couple of fields under. http://tinypic.com/r/kaodua/5

Comment: it seems alright. and there is value updated for the filename column right? that .txt file?

Answer (score 0):

using System.IO; 
 protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
            {
                string FileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;

```
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;AttachDbFilename=E:\\Assignment\\App_Data\\MyDatabase.mdf;Integrated Security=True;User Instance=True");
            SqlCommand cmd;
            con.Open();
            cmd = new SqlCommand("UPDATE application SET filename= '" + FileName + "' WHERE stulastname = '" + DropDownList1.SelectedValue + "' ");
            cmd.Connection = con;
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            string path = Server.MapPath("~/App_Data/userfiles");
            bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(path);
            if (!isExists)
                System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(path);
            var file = Path.Combine(path, FileUpload1.FileName);
            FileUpload1.SaveAs(file);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Include 
using System.IO;

Comment: I just tried this and it didn't even post the filename the database this time

Comment: i also have added using System.IO

Answer (score 0):

Just now i check ur code. 
 pls change

string FileName = FileUpload1.PostedFile.FileName;

to

string FileName = FileUpload1.FileName;
and pls add

con.Close();

after

cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

It wont update the database if the dropdown value not getting properly .so pls check DropDownList1.SelectedValue is matching with db column value

Comment: I have changed the line which has string FileName and i have added con.Close();

Comment: my dropdownlist also does properly get the values from the database

Comment: everything looks right so i am very confused as to why it does not work